# In which table is a path alias stored?

Tags: database

I need to make a query to get the path alias used for a node.  In which table is it stored?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They're in the aptly named `url_alias` table, but you shouldn't query it directly. The path alias manager service is preferable:

```
$alias = \Drupal::service('path.alias_manager')
    ->getAliasByPath("/node/$nid");
```

As always, inject the service if you can.

Comment: This is correct: The database table used from the service is an implementation detail modules should not depend upon. The service could be replaced from another one, or the service provided by Drupal core could decide changing method to store those data.

Answer (score 1):

There is a `url_alias` table in the database that holds source and alias records.

Comment: there is a field there called "pid"  where is the node id?

Comment: If you are doing this from code, I suggest doing it the way Clive said. I assumed you were in a SQL tool. It does not store entity IDs directly. In a SQL tool, you'd query the source table for "/node/" + node_id to get the alias.

Answer (score 1):

For drupal 8 there is a table  `path_alias` that holds source and alias records.

Answer (score 1):

The url alias field is stored in the “path_alias” table, and when querying, you can retrieve the data you are looking for based on the table field path.